# convert .json file to .csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have the following .json file:

```
data:   
    0:  
        area_code   "1A40"
        blacklist   0
        cost_center "Payments "
        country "Colombia"
        created_date    "Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT"
        .
        .
        .
    1:
        area_code   "1A42"
        blacklist   0
        cost_center "Payments "
        country "Colombia"
        created_date    "Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT"
        .
        .
        .
    2:{...}
    .
    .
    .
    1000:{...}

next url: "eyJzdGFydElu...="
```

I am using the following code to convert my .json file to csv :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('Data.json')['data']
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

when I open the file from google sheet it brings me this way:

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {'area_code': '1A40', 'blacklist': 0, 'cost_center': 'Payments', 'country': 'Colombia', 'created_date': 'Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT', 'deleted_date': None, 'department': 'Core Enablers', 'display_name': 'Oscar', 'division': 'IT', ...'} |
| 1 | {'area_code': '1A41', 'blacklist': 0, 'cost_center': 'Payments', 'country': 'Colombia', 'created_date': 'Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT', 'deleted_date': None, 'department': 'Core Enablers', 'display_name': 'Oscar', 'division': 'IT', ...'} |
| ... | {...} |
| 999 | {...} |

What I'm needing is for the information to be listed in the sheet without repeating the headers for each cell

|  | area_code | blacklist | cost_center | country | created_date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1A40 | 0 | Payments | Colombia | Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT | ... |
| 1 | 1A42 | 0 | Payments | Colombia | Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT | ... |
| ... | ... | .... | ... | ... | .... | ... |
| 999 | ... | .... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Maybe you could tell me how I can list it like this?

Comment: That's not even remotely a JSON file.

Comment: So why don't you just provide us with a representative example that is JSON instead of making us guess what your shorthand means?

Comment: Thank you! I tell you that they also recommended me to use gpt chat, he incredibly also gave me a solution! greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json', 'r') as f_in:
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(f_in)['data'])

print(df)

#to save to CSV:
#df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Prints:

```
  area_code  blacklist cost_center   country                   created_date
0      1A40          0   Payments   Colombia  Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT
1      1A42          0   Payments   Colombia  Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT
```

---

Contents of `data.json` file:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "area_code": "1A40",
            "blacklist": 0,
            "cost_center": "Payments ",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "created_date": "Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT"
        },
        {
            "area_code": "1A42",
            "blacklist": 0,
            "cost_center": "Payments ",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "created_date": "Thu, 03 Jul 2014 12:57:02 GMT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand the dicts in the list. you can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('Data.json')['data'].apply(pd.Series)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```